# Как предотвратить попадание всего массива в цикл вызова класса, нужен только его последний элемент?

Tags: javascript

У меня реализован функционал через класс Task. Этот класс вызывает цикл, вследствие чего каждый элемент массива попадает в отдельную карточку. Карточки создает пользователь при нажиме на кнопку формы, в которые попадает введенный ним текст. Данные введенные пользователем, попадают в массив, на основании чего цикл выводит карточки.
При нажиме первый раз - карточка формируется одна, как и задумывалось.
Когда пользователь нажимает второй раз - выводится вторая карточка и дублируется первая. Но мне надо, чтобы карточки выводились без дубляжа. Что мне нужно подправить в этом участке кода?
Только при перезагрузке страницы дубляж исчезает

```
let tasks = [];

function createTaskList(tasks) {


    // Динамический вывод задач. Их количество зависит от количество элементов массива tasks
    tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
      new Task(
        task
      ).render();
      
    });

    // Превращение JS массива в строчный и добавление его в localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('allTodo', JSON.stringify(tasks));

  } //end function createTaskList
  createTaskList(tasks);
```

Comment: для начала замените tasks.forEach((tasks, на tasks.forEach((task, .. И добавьте больше деталей

Comment: Какие делали нужны?

Comment: Побольше кода, ожиданий и прочего

Comment: Вот этой строчки не хватало для очистки предыдущего рендеринга taskList.innerHTML = '';

Comment: Да вот и как это определить по вашему вопросу? Задавайте пожалуйста развернутые вопросы чтоб читатель мог помочь вам и не про100 терять время

Comment: @AzizUmarov: человек развернул, добавив кучу переводов строк :)